# problems reading 2d byte array from a text file

Tags: java, arrays, io, byte

I'm having problems reading a byte array back from a text file that I had already written the byte array to.

Here is the code for writing the byte array to the file

```
    FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(new File("C:\\Users\\lvannini\\Desktop\\FileSystem\\diskFiles\\", fileName));
    for(int i = 0; i < 64; ++i){
        for(int j = 0; j < 64; ++j)
            fout.write(String.valueOf(ldisk[i][j]).getBytes());
        fout.write(System.lineSeparator().getBytes()); //write line break;
```

As far as I'm aware, this part is working correctly, because my output text file contains the appropriate contents of the 2d array I am using. An example of the first 9 lines of the text file are printed as follows:

```
00-1-16000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00024000700000000000000090000000000071000100001100000000000800000000
-1-1-1-1000000000000-1-1-1-1000000000000-1-1-1-1000000000000-1-1-1-1000000000000
-1-1-1-1000000000000-1-1-1-1000000000000-1-1-1-1000000000000-1-1-1-1000000000000
-1-1-1-1000000000000-1-1-1-1000000000000-1-1-1-1000000000000-1-1-1-1000000000000
-1-1-1-1000000000000-1-1-1-1000000000000-1-1-1-1000000000000-1-1-1-1000000000000
-1-1-1-1000000000000-1-1-1-1000000000000-1-1-1-1000000000000-1-1-1-1000000000000
10010010000001979899000021021111110000900000000000000010000000000000000800000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

However, using this following code to read back from the file into the 2D array:

```
FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\lvannini\\Desktop\\FileSystem\\diskFiles\\" + fileName);
    for(int i = 0; i < 64; ++i)
        fin.read(ldisk[i]);

    fin.close();
```

gives me the actual ASCII values of each byte being read in. For instance, after reading in the first line of the text file, my 2d array, ldisk[0], contains:

```
48 48 45 49 45 49 54 48 48 48 . . .
```

Where am I losing the translation from the byte values to the ascii values? I'm suspecting I'm saving the byte values to the text file incorrectly. Any advice/responses are very much appreciated! Thanks again.

Comment: what is the type of ldisk array?

Comment: ldisk is a byte[][] array

Comment: but how come you write to 2D but you read from 1D?!!!

Comment: read accepts a byte[] array as a parameter. Therefore it turns each 64 byte line from the file, 64 times into the 2D array

Comment: Is there any particular reason for translating the byte value to String and than retrieving the byte representation of this String?
If not, you can easily fix this problem by writing the byte directly to the file.

Answer (score 1):

> Where am I losing the translation from the byte values to the ASCII values?

[`FileInputStream.read()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html#read()) is giving you the ASCII code for the byte. See [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/), which reveals you're not losing the translation.

Just cast that ASCII code to a character code:

```
char c = (char)fin.read(ldisk[i]);
```

*OR* subtract 48 from it to get the integer value:

```
-48 + fin.read(ldisk[i])
```

You still have to deal with the minus signs taking up bytes, so your

```
for(int i = 0; i < 64; ++i)
```

is inadequate with `64` as limit when there are minus signs in the file.

Comment: I can't write chars into the byte[][] array directly upfront. I guess what I really want is for some sort of input stream to read the byte (for instance, byte 0) and store that same value (0) instead of the ascii value for 0 (48).

Comment: See my edit. You only need to subtract 48 from the ASCII integer to get its actual integer value.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with FileInputStream. There are many ways get ASCII values of each byte being read but the easiest is probably BufferedReader with defined charset.

```
Charset charset = Charset.forName("US-ASCII");
BufferedReader in = Files.newBufferedReader(C:\\Users\\lvannini\\Desktop\\FileSystem\\diskFiles\\" + fileName, charset);

String line;
while((line = in.readLine()) != null)
{
   //do something with your input
}
in.close();
```